# How can i know when a functions timed out?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I was setting up my firebase functions and got myself into a function timeout, (which was more than 60 sec) so my question is, is there a trigger or something to trigger my custom function to notify me or my users that a function has timed out?

Comment: did your webserver send a timeout ?

Answer (score 2):

There is not.  Your only option is to [enable retries](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/retries) on your function in the Cloud console so that it gets executed again on failure.  If you do this, you should be certain that the timeout is temporary and will eventually recover.  Otherwise, your function will get retried maybe more times that you'd like to pay for.

Comment: Can i create a set timeout function e.g terminate a function after 90 sec, or will that bring a problem?

Comment: It will not work after the function times out.  Cloud Functions will shut everything down after the function terminates for whatever reason.